# What does it mean for a matrix to have a vertex set as its subscript

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, notation

This might or might not be author specific, but in Algebraic Statistics by Seth Sullivant the author uses a notation of $S_{K, K}$ for example. So far I have not been able to find out what it means. Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEJHw.png). For reference, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43Wn6.png) is the syntax the author uses for an induced subgraphs.

Comment: @MorganRodgers would you be willing to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @JohannesKloos Posted now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common to index the entries of a matrix with the elements of a set in situations where it would technically be possible to order the set in some way, but the way in which the objects are numbered would be unimportant.

One example of this is using the vertices of a graph. To give an explicit adjacency matrix of a graph, we would need to order the vertices in some way to say which vertex corresponds to the "first" row/column of the matrix, etc.  But the way in which we decide to order the vertices is really unimportant in terms of the properties of the matrix. So it is nice notationally to just say that there is a correspondence between the rows/columns of our matrix and the elements of our set.

(I started to say something about your specific example, but it is missing the explanation of what $T$ and $S$ represent so I am not able to say a lot; I would assume that $S$ is the adjacency matrix of $G$, and that the rows/columns are indiced by $V$, and so $S_{K,K}$ gives a nice description of the submatrix obtained by taking the rows and columns corresponding to the vertices in the induced subgraph, which is the adjacency matrix for $G_{K}$.)

From a more advanced viewpoint, this can align with thinking of a matrix as really representing a linear transformation. You can think of having a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with the vertices of the graph as a basis; so elements of this vector space are linear combinations of vertices. This can be denoted by $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. Then we are really thinking of the incidence matrix as a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^{K} \to \mathbb{R}^{K}$ that sends each vertex to the formal sum of its neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and any subsets $I, J \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\}$, the notation $A_{I,J}$ is a semi-common way to refer to the submatrix where you take the rows indexed by $I$ and the columns indexed by $J$. That is what is going on in this example.